# Building an app bundle for a non-Cocoa C++ Mac Project

Tags: c++, macos, xcode4.3, building

I am building a C++ OpenGL card game in Xcode 4.3.3, with the intention of running it on both 64-bit and 32-bit Macs, which is not my problem. My problem is that I have reached a point in the development of the program where I would like to test that it works on a different 32-bit Mac (mine is 64-bit) without having to install Xcode. This, obviously, requires me exporting it as an .app. I can find and run the exported Unix Executable File from my project, after some cd'ing, through Terminal, but that is undesirable for me and the intended audience of the program. I have trawled the google and Stack Overflow, looking for anything to help me, but all the things mentioning Archiving seem to have been unsuccessful with my particular project, and I think that's because it's a C++ command line tool project. So, can someone please help me export my project as a .app?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this would be to create a Cocoa project, go to 'build phases' and remove all the objective-c frameworks from the 'link with libraries' build phase, remove any objective-c files added by the template (app delegate, etc.) and then replace main.c with your main.cpp file.

There's nothing really special about a Cocoa project except for the fact that it links against Cocoa and calls NSApplicationMain() from its main() function.

There are also a bunch of .plist entries used by Cocoa which you'll no longer need. But they won't affect the way OS X treats your application.

Comment: This worked perfectly and was exactly what I wanted, and after a bit of jiggery-pokey with the settings the Archive worked it gave me my .app, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thank you! Was afraid I'd have to learn Objectice-C++ to do this. 
Why don't you get the option to choose C++ as language when creating a new Cocoa application in Xcode if it's this simple?

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for an XCode Settings solution but here's my current way to create an app:

You have to take your binary file (let say `myapp`) and put it in "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/myapp" then it can now be launched as a .app. That's a trick.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to the targets folder in the file navigator on the left, and there will be an executable listed there. Left click on that executable and click "show in finder". (I'm describing from memory so I may have the exact details wrong.) The file path is ridiculously long (there is an arbitrary alphanumerical pathname involved, I have **no** idea why), so you probably won't be able to find it with the command line.

If you want you can change the extension of the file from nothing to ".app", it shouldn't affect the nature of the file at all. Also if you want a custom icon, you can "get info" on it in the finder, then click on the icon in the info window, and use Cmd-V to paste it in (obviously you have to have your icon copied to the clipboard). There is also a way to do this inside of Xcode, but I don't remember it.

Comment: Would the down-voter care to make a suggestion about what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Not sure who did, but I tried what you suggested and it didn't work :( when I tried to run it said "The Classic Environment is no longer supported" so I imagine your information is merely outdated. Besides, merely renaming the Unix exe doesn't create the internal file structure of an app, something it seems only Xcode can do.