# How do I turn my C++ code into a .app file?

Tags: c++, macos

I have started learning C++ recently and i'm wondering how I can turn my .cpp file with my code into a .app file that I can give to someone to run on their mac? I mean if I took a .cpp file I could do "g++ -o main main.cpp" and "./main" but I want a .app file that I just double click and it runs the program

Comment: rename the file?  A .cpp file is just a text file so treat it like one.

Comment: I already tried that and it doesnt open.

Comment: Well, `.cpp` is source code, `.app` is an executable application bundle. You'll have to compile your source code into a functional application. Xcode is Apple's tool of choice to do that. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365612/building-an-app-bundle-for-a-non-cocoa-c-mac-project).

Comment: how do I actually compile it though? @rickdenhaan

Comment: I haven't worked with Xcode in a few years, but IIRC it used to have an Archive feature that allowed you to build the application and export a .app file. Not sure if that's still the case today or if they've moved the build and export features somewhere else.